# Keras NN - Learning a simple formula

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I'm struggling with a seemingly simple problem and could really use your help! I'm starting to learn about neural networks. I thought I would create a simple example to get started, using one dimensional inputs X and one dimensional outputs Y. When I first started with Y = 2X, the neural network was able to learn it very well over 1000 epochs. However, when I increased the complexity of the formula to below, it completely breaks apart (the MSE is very high).

X = random numbers between 0 and 100 (one-dimensional)

Y = (8(x^3)) + 5

I have tried adding more hidden layers and epochs without much success. Could anyone provide me with some guidance on where I'm going wrong in my method?

Much appreciated!

Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
# fix random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(7)

def generate_Y(X):
    return np.add(np.power(np.multiply(X, 2.0), 3.0), 5.0).T[0]

X = np.random.rand(100,1)
X = np.multiply(X, 100.0)
Y = generate_Y(X)

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(12))
model.add(Dense(12))
model.add(Dense(12))
model.add(Dense(1))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10000, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

test_X = np.random.rand(10,1)
test_X = np.multiply(test_X, 500.0)
test_Y = generate_Y(test_X)
preds = model.predict(test_X)

print preds
diffs = np.subtract(preds.T[0], test_Y)
print diffs
```

MSE: mean_squared_error: 73360074604544.00%

Prediction vs actual diffs: 
[ 4.97601229e+05 -1.60322447e+06 -7.85835700e+08 -7.00977203e+08
 -7.52094155e+08 -1.88780991e+08 -1.64643340e+08 -9.38229901e+08
 -2.02173897e+08  4.45327360e+05]

Comment: You are not using any of the activation functions like sigmoid or ReLU.

Comment: I thought the sigmoid function was better used for classification rather than regression problems? I tried adding those activation functions and it didn't improve the result.

Comment: The formula you are trying to learn is clearly non linear, therefore you have to use some non linearity activation as @shubam Panchal suggested. Please show the code after this update.

Comment: and `generate_Y`returns just a value... are you shure about the usage of `.T[0]`?